# Import .xlsx File in R Error: Workbook has no worksheets

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I want to analyze xlsx files generated by a qPCR apparatus with R but I can't open these files unless I save them in excel before loading them in R.

I am using the command read.xlsx() from openxlsx package:

```
library(openxlsx)
my_file <- "~/my_file.xlsx"
read.xlsx(my_file,1)
```

I get this message:

```
Error in read.xlsx.default(my_file, sheet = "0", skipEmptyCols = TRUE) : 
Workbook has no worksheets
```

The only way this works is if I save the xlsx file first in excel, is there a way to bypass this step?

Comment: How did you generate qPCR apparatus? Can we have the code and reproducible example?

Comment: Was anyone every able to assist with this? I have this same problem as well

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because you haven't called the file by it's proper name? Try;

```
read.xlsx("my_file.xlsx", sheet = 1)
```

Comment: sorry it was a mistake in the code I paste, the file name is correct

Comment: As per @Ronak's comment on the question; I think we need a reproducible example. I would _guess_ that the qPCR is producing a slightly non-standard .xlsx file that Excel can handle ok but is confusing R...

Answer (score 0):

Open the xlxs file in Excel and allow editing (the yellow bar below the menus) and resave the file. Reload the xlxs in R and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I want to skip this step actually, I want to be able to open the xlsx file directly in R

Comment: I think there's a package called "pcr" available for handling the raw data out of the qPCR machine but not sure it can take "xlsx" as an input.

Answer (score 0):

library(xlsx)

my_file <- read.xlsx("~/my_file.xlsx",h=T, sheetIndex = 1)